# Not Writing To JSON file. fs.writeFile not working

Tags: json, node.js, fs, writefile

I have this fs.writeFile code that is suppose to update the localdata.json file when a newWorkout is POST'ed to the database, this takes local state data in an attempt to write to the file..

it wont work though and throws a , TypeError: fs.writeFile is not a function error.. working on the fix now but if anyone sees anything help is appreciated.

```
 fs.writeFile(
        "./localdata.json",
        JSON.stringify(newWorkout.eventDateTime),
        "utf-8",
        function(err) {
          if (err) throw err
          console.log("Done!")
        }
      )
```

Comment: So what exactly is `fs`?

Comment: @robertklep FS is nodes File System - https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: Well, not exactly, because if it were, `fs.writeFile` _would_ be a function.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - as it currently stands, there's not enough information here for a sensible answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include:

```
var fs = require("fs");
...the rest of your code...
```

Comment: `const fs = require("fs")` was included @11AND2

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are working in a Node.js environment, is seems like `fs` is not a proper Node.js File System object. Copied from the [Node.js 10.x documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/fs.html#fs_file_system):

> To use this module:

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

Comment: If `fs` wasn't loaded, using `fs.writeFile` would throw another error (`fs is not defined`). In this case, `fs` seems to be defined, only `fs.writeFile` is not a function (because it's overwritten, or `fs` has been overwritten after declaration).

Comment: @robertklep Thanks, I see what you mean. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Nodes File System cannot be used "browser side" these calls are meant to happen on the server side of things.